# Test-DbaNetworkLatency how to load query from a script file

Tags: sql-server, dbatools

I am using `Test-DbaNetworkLatency` from `dbatools` (https://docs.dbatools.io/#Test-DbaNetworkLatency) to check the network latency between my application server and SQL server instance.
But `Test-DbaNetworkLatency` command line query doesn't support query string more than 128 characters. I have a big query statement to test. How can I load a query from saved sql file?

Comment: Have you tried reading the T-SQL script file into a variable and passing the variable as parameter in your script to the cmdlet? e.g. `$query = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllText("C:\Scripts\YourBigScript.sql")`

Comment: Out of curiosity, what query are you trying to send? The purpose of this cmdlet is to establish a SQL connection and run a *simple* query (emphasis mine).

Comment: @DanGuzman yes it works. Thanks